# The way to find the most near table after certain text in html, using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am parsing a HTML data using BeautifulSoup.

The HTML I am parsing looks like

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> ABC </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> DEF </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> GHI </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
   <body>
</html>
```

(ABC,DEF and GHI are names of below tables)

In this html, what I need to do is.

First, check there is "ABC" or "GHI" text in html.

Second, find the first table after(next_silbings) text "ABC" and "GHI" (So first and third table with border="1")

(In other words, I need to find the name of table(ABC), and find the first table with border="1")

First, Using the

```
findAll(text = "regular expression")
```

I can solve the First problem.

to achieve the Second I tried to use next_siblings or something like that but I failed to achieve the Second.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> ABC </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> DEF </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
      <table class = "nb">
         <tr>
            <td> <p> GHI </p> </td>
         <tr>
      </table>
      <table border = "1">
       ...
      </table>
   <body>
</html>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# First, find and check there is "ABC" or "GHI" text in html.
nameTable = doc.getElementByReg('ABC', tag='td')
if nameTable:
    nameTable = nameTable.getParent('table')
    # Second, find the first table after(next_silbings) text "ABC"
    table = nameTable.getNext('table')  # Using next
    print(table['border'])

    # Or, Using index positioning
    table = doc.getElement('table', start=nameTable._end)
    print(table['border'])
```

Result:

```
1
1
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples